# GWT XML config parse error in dev mode server

Tags: java, spring, gwt

i have an application using spring 3.2.1, gwt 2.4 and hibernate.

This deploys fine in tomcat and runs without errors.

When i try to start a GWT dev mode server for development, the server fails with following error

```
  Loading modules
     com.my.app.App
        [ERROR] Unexpected error while processing XML
  java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.ReflectiveParser$Impl.startElement(ReflectiveParser.java:187)
    at org.allcolor.xml.parser.CShaniSaxParser.parseStartTag(CShaniSaxParser.java:1393)
    at org.allcolor.xml.parser.CXmlParser.parseSTARTTag(CXmlParser.java:1405)
    at org.allcolor.xml.parser.CXmlParser.parse(CXmlParser.java:948)
    at org.allcolor.xml.parser.CShaniSaxParser.parse(CShaniSaxParser.java:767)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.ReflectiveParser$Impl.parse(ReflectiveParser.java:347)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.ReflectiveParser$Impl.access$200(ReflectiveParser.java:68)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.ReflectiveParser.parse(ReflectiveParser.java:418)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefLoader.nestedLoad(ModuleDefLoader.java:296)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefLoader$1.load(ModuleDefLoader.java:198)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefLoader.doLoadModule(ModuleDefLoader.java:324)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefLoader.loadFromClassPath(ModuleDefLoader.java:156)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.loadModule(DevModeBase.java:992)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.loadModule(DevMode.java:557)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.doStartup(DevMode.java:443)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.startUp(DevModeBase.java:1058)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.run(DevModeBase.java:811)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.main(DevMode.java:311)
  [ERROR] shell failed in doStartup method
```

As far as i can see the xml file is found but the document locator in com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.ReflectiveParser.java is not set and fail with a NullPointerException when used.

Any ideas what my mistake is?

Thanks
Sven

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `org.allcolor.xml.parser` sets itself as the XML parser for `javax.xml`. If you don't need `org.allcolor` for client-side code, then remove it from the classpath of the DevMode.

FYI, we have a similar problem with Xerces: HtmlUnit (used to run `GWTTestCase` tests by default) needs Xerces, but Xerces then registers as an XML parser to the JVM and breaks the module parsing in the same way. We thus have to remove the `META-INF` from the Xerces JAR.

Comment: Thanks for the information.

In fact this parser is used in my application and can not be removed (at least i don't want to ;-))


My way to get GWT dev mode server running, was to use conditional breakpoints in my IDE, which set this locators.
This helps to run in debug mode.
Anyhow i consider your answer as solution.

Thanks Thomas

Comment: The parser is used for client-side code? or only on the server-side? Server-side dependencies live in `WEB-INF/lib`, there's no point having them in the DevMode classpath (note: I'm not talking about the _build path_)

Comment: I'm fairly new to this whole GWT dev mode server thing.
Would this mean i had to start GWT dev mode server with -noserver and deploy it also by i.e. tomcat?

Comment: No. Just put server-side dependencies and code into `WEB-INF` (like any webapp), and only include client-side dependencies and code in the DevMode classpath. You don't configure Tomcat with your server-side deps in its classpath right? It's the same for DevMode.